# window.web3.eth.Contract no longer works. How do i now connect to a contract?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, metamask

reading through this resource, https://docs.metamask.io/guide/provider-migration.html#summary-of-breaking-changes, it seems it is still possible to interact with a contract using window.ethereum,

eg (taken from the above link)

```
 const transactionHash = await ethereum.request({
method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
params: [
  {
    to: '0x...',
    'from': '0x...',
    value: '0x...',
    // And so on...
  },
],
});
```

but I cannot figure out how to connect to the contract.

What do Ireplace this with?

```
contract = await new window.web3.eth.Contract(ABI,ADDRESS);
```

I am using the web3 library via this resource
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js

my simple script is below;

```
var account = null;
var contract = null;
const ABI = "the abi is here"
const ADDRESS = "contract address is here"; 



async function asyncCall() {
    console.log('async');
    if (window.ethereum) {
      try {
        const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
        account = accounts[0];
        document.getElementById('wallet-address').textContent = account;
        
    // this is the bit i'm stuck on currently
        contract = await new window.web3.eth.Contract(ABI,ADDRESS);
    //  
        var mintButton = document.getElementById('mint');

        mintButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
            console.log('minting');
            contract.methods.mint(account).send({from:account,value:"100"});
            
        });
         
        var totalsupply = await contract.methods.totalsupply().call();
        document.getElementById('ttt').textContent = totalsupply;
      } catch (error) {
        if (error.code === 4001) {
        console.log('User rejected request');
           
        }

        console.log(error);
      }
    }
}

asyncCall();
```

Answer (score 1):

So instead of using `window.web3` since Metamask no longer injects it into webpages, you can do this before making the call to get the contract:

```js
const Web3 = require('web3');

// Create Web3 instance
const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum); // Where window.etherem is your provider.
```

You can then get your contract by calling:

```js
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, ADDRESS);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
let provider = window.ethereum;
if (provider) {
  await provider.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
  this.web3 = new Web3(provider);
  this.contract = new this.web3.eth.Contract(abi_v2, address);
}
```